# How to sync All Textbox1 in Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

My workbook has five sheets with text boxes.
Sheet1, Sheet2, ......, and Sheet5.

And the code below is on every sheet.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Else
  If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
  ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End If

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox1.Value & "*"
End If

End Sub
```

I would like to synchronize the `TEXTBOXES` on all sheets.

For example, if I type text in `TEXTBOX1` of Sheet1, the same text will be entered in `TEXTBOX1` of all other sheets.

And I also want to know how to clear `TEXTBOX` on every sheet at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) put the following code in new Module of your project

```
Public dontDoThat As Boolean ' a public variable, visible throughout all your project you'll use to give way to synchronizing activity

Option Explicit

Sub Synchronize(txt As String, shtName As String)
    dontDoThat = True ' set your public variable to True and prevent subsequent TextBox1_Change() events to run it again

    Dim sht As Variant
    For Each sht In Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")
        If sht <> shtName Then Worksheets(sht).TextBox1.Text = txt 
    Next

    dontDoThat = False ' set your public variable to False and allow subsequent TextBox1_Change() events to run it 
End Sub
```

2) change your `TextBox1_Change()` event in all your sheets as follows

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Not dontDoThat Then Synchronize Me.TextBox1.Text, Me.Name 'call Synchronize() only if your public variable allows it to

    ...
    (rest of your previous code follows)
    ...

End Sub
```

To clear all textboxes just clear one of them

Comment: Change “ActiveSheet” to “Me” in all your TextBox1_Change() event handlers. If my answer above solves you question you may consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add module in your project and add this Sub there (adjusting names of sheets and TextBoxes, if needed):

```
Sub SetText(txt As String)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Text = txt
    Worksheets("Sheet2").TextBox1.Text = txt
    Worksheets("Sheet3").TextBox1.Text = txt
    Worksheets("Sheet4").TextBox1.Text = txt
    Worksheets("Sheet5").TextBox1.Text = txt
End Sub
```

Then, in Change event for every TextBox add this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    SetText Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

To clear all text you can set `.TextBox1.Text = ""`